# Bluetooth to 3.5mm audio jack

Tags: audio, bluetooth, adapter, headphones

I want to connect my laptop's (and cellphone's) bluetooth to an audio jack. Of course there has to be some sort of receiver on the audio jack side. Are there any devices for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through numerous pages on 'Bluetooth to 3.5mm' on Amazon and I think found the device I was looking for. They are called Bluetooth stereo gateways. [Ventev SoundCLIP](http://www.alternativewireless.com/ventev-bluetooth-handsfree/ventev-soundclip-bluetooth-handsfree.html) has a wall/car charger, headset output, and supports A2DP (Bluetooth v2.1). My phone supports Bluetooth 2.0 with EDR so it supports A2DP.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean so that you can play from the laptop via bluetooth to a device you can plug any 3.5mm jack into? If so then yes, several are on the market. http://www.expansys.com/d.aspx?i=160887 is one example. As you can see from that picture the provided earphones connect via a standard jack so you could plug compatible in in their place. Mine, also by Jabra but a clips-to-your-collar affair rather like then the dog-tag look that one has, doesn't seem to be made any more but I'm sure I've seen similar from other manufacturers.

Your laptop's bluetooth stack would have to support sending audio data over Bluetooth in a fashion that the receiver understands, so you'd have to verify that. I've never used mine this way so I couldn't tell you (mine has always been used with my phone).

Comment: Yes something like this. Is there something a bit more heavy duty.. I want to connect it to my stereo

Comment: How do you mean "heavy duty"? If your stereo has a microphone input you should have no problem plugging something like this in via a normal 3.5mm-jack-to-3.5mm-jack cable. The most quality related problem you are likely to have are from the limitations of the bluetooth connection rather than the rest of the arrangement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something that is powered by AC. Does this kind of device have a special name or can you show me others like this. I've looked on Amazon but couldn't find it

Comment: They are all likely be designed mainly for portable use so will have batteries, though there is nothing to stop you keeping the charger plugged into the wall rather than relying on the battery at all. Look for "bluetooth headphones" then look at the specs/pictures to see which have jacks and which have permanently connected earpieces. Make sure you get one that supports A2DP and that your laptop's BT stack supports it too or you'll be stuck with lower quality mono sound rather than the better quality (and in stereo) that A2DP provides.

Answer (score 2):

Does it *have* to be Bluetooth ? For 802.11 there are low cost solutions like [Airport Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/) which is a very small WiFi router with audio streaming capabilities.

Comment: I would like it to also stream from my cellphone too

Comment: @srand: you might want to mention the cellphone requirement in your question